# NameError: name 'logged' is not defined, Flask Python

Tags: python, variables, flask

I have a Python code with using framework Flask, that check if admin logged (logged = True) to render admin page, if admin is not logged (logged = False), redirecting to login page.

```
@app.route('/admin_login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def admin_login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login = request.form['login']
        passsword = request.form['password']

        if (login == 'admin') and (passsword == 'admin_pass'):
            logged = True
            return redirect('/admin_page'), logged
        else:
            return "Wrond login and passsword!"

    else:
        return render_template('admin_login.html')


@app.route('/admin_page')
def admin_page():
    if logged == True:
        return render_template('admin_page.html')
    else:
        return redirect('/admin_login')
```

But I get an error in `if logged == True:` - `NameError: name 'logged' is not defined`. I tried to make `logged` global but it didn't helped. So how can I make `logged` defined and use it in function `admin_page`?

Comment: A global variable in a web server makes no sense.  If you had made that work, then if *anybody* was logged in as an administrator, then *anybody else* could freely visit /admin_page!

Comment: I know it, I just want to know how to use returned logged in other func

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid having a global `logged_in` variable on the server. Then anybody will be allowed to use your website after a successful login! You should use a session variable instead.

Session data is stored on top of cookies and encrypted. For this encryption, a Flask application needs a defined SECRET_KEY. A Session object is also a dictionary object containing key-value pairs.

Add this near the top of your main script if you haven't already got it:

```
from flask import Flask, session, redirect, url_for, escape, request, flash
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'any random string’
```

Then change your function `admin_login()` to set the session variable:

```
@app.route('/admin_login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def admin_login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login = request.form['login']
        passsword = request.form['password']

        if not 'logged_in' in session:
            if (login == 'admin') and (passsword == 'admin_pass'):
                session['logged_in'] = True
                return redirect(url_for("admin_page"))
            else:
                flash("Wrong login and passsword!")
                return render_template('admin_login.html')
        else:
            return redirect(url_for("admin_page"))

    else:
        if "logged_in" in session:
            return redirect(url_for("admin_page"))

        return render_template("admin_login.html")
```

Then change your `admin_page()` function to check this session variable:

```
@app.route('/admin_page')
def admin_page():
    if 'logged_in' in session:
        return render_template('admin_page.html')
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('admin_login'))
```

You would also need a logout end point to pop out the session variable:

```
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
   session.pop('logged_in', None)
   return redirect(url_for('index'))
```